# tampermonkey script to open website doesnt work

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tampermonkey

I use this script to open a specific link in a `div` of a webpage:

```
     // ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://www.tampermonkey.net/index.php?version=4.13&ext=dhdg&updated=true
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tampermonkey.net
// @grant        none
 // @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

 $(document).ready(function()
                   {
let url = $(".cta-button-container__item").attr('href');
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

the inspect elements for the link in the page is:

```
<div class="cta-button-container__item">
                    <a href="/content/pdf/xxxx.pdf" title="Download this book in PDF format" target="_blank" rel="noopener" class="c-button c-button--blue c-button__icon-right test-bookpdf-link" data-track="click" data-track-action="Book download - pdf" data-track-label="">
                        <svg width="12" height="14" viewBox="0 0 12 14" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><path d="M7 7.269v-6.271c0-.551-.448-.998-1-.998-.556 0-1 .447-1 .998v6.271l-1.5-1.547c-.375-.387-1.01-.397-1.401-.006l.016-.016c-.397.397-.391 1.025-.001 1.416l3.178 3.178c.392.392 1.024.391 1.415 0l3.178-3.178c.392-.392.391-1.025-.001-1.416l.016.016c-.397-.397-1.018-.388-1.401.006l-1.5 1.547zm-7 5.731c0-.552.456-1 1.002-1h9.995c.554 0 1.002.444 1.002 1 0 .552-.456 1-1.002 1h-9.995c-.554 0-1.002-.444-1.002-1z" fill="#fff"></path></svg>
                        <span>Download book PDF</span>
                    </a>
                </div>
```

Unfortunately tampermonkey says no script is running.

Comment: You need to run your jQuery code in a [document.ready handler](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/), not an IIFE

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, i updated the code but still doesn't work

Comment: Why did you put it inside a `main()` function? Remove that too. You just need `$(document).ready(...)`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan, I saw many examples use it inside a "main". However, I removed it and still doesn't work.

Comment: What URL should the script run on?

Comment: @double-beep what do I mean by that

Comment: If you want the website where the script will work then it is :https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-3-319-40871-2

Comment: @double-beep, it kinda worked but now there are two problems:  
    

1) i wanted it to work on all tabs opened with the same domain name (springerlink.com) and 

2) the new page says "page unavailable : the information you are looking for .....". i think the script opened a different link or so.

Answer (score 2):

after more search and i edited the script and it works perfectly:

```
    // ==UserScript==
// @name         New Userscript
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://link.springer.com/book/*/*
// @icon         https://www.google.com/s2/favicons?domain=tampermonkey.net
// @grant        none
 // @require https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js
// ==/UserScript==

 $(document).ready(function()
                   {
    let url = $(".cta-button-container__item a").attr('href');
    window.location.href = url;
});
```

I forgot to add the `a` which is equivalent to `.find("a")` . I changed the url of the filter to `https://link.springer.com/book/*/*`. the (*/*) just means any address beginning with the previous link.